# Will an indexed View gets executed every time when a new row is inserted?

Tags: sql-server, index

Let's say we have two tables: Customers(CustID, FirstName, OrderID) and Orders(ID, Date, Amount) and there is an indexed view join on CustID and ID and have a clustered index on these two columns.

so if I add a new record in Customers table, will the view gets executed first? so it will be like every time you modify any row in one of these two tables, the view needs to be executed, which is very tedious and not efficient .

Comment: Your question is likely answered here: [Indexed View Maintenance in Execution Plans](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/03/sql-plan/indexed-view-maintenance-in-execution-plans).

Answer (score 2):

That’s not actually how an indexes view works when it comes to the underlying tables having their data modified.

Views that have a clustered index are no longer just relying on the tables they reference to satisfy the query. They have data stored on disk as if they are a table and every time a row is added, changed or deleted from one of the underlying tables then the data in the view is also updated as part of that transaction. Explicit interaction with the view is not needed to sync the data in the view with its underlying tables.

Read this [post](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-indexed-views-the-basics/) that has more details